# Expo-constants causing EPERM: operation not permitted lstat

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-unimodules

I've been trying to run my RN app using `react-native run-android` but it keep crashing before it loads with this error message below:

> events.js:292
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
> 'C:\Users...\android\app\build\generated\assets\expo-constants\debug\app.config'
> Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
> at NodeWatcher. (C:\Users...\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
> at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21) {   errno: -4048,   code: 'EPERM',   syscall: 'lstat',   path:
> 'C:\Users\...android\app\build\generated\assets\expo-constants\debug\app.config'
> }

I have searched online, but could not see any solution for my problem. How do I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.